# System.NotSupportedException: 'Could not activate JNI Handle

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, maui

We are in the process of converting our Xamarin.Forms app to MAUI application.
We are reusing the Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging (123.1.2.2) in our MAUI application.
We are receiving a error while deploying the app.

System.NotSupportedException: 'Could not activate JNI Handle 0x7ff89520c0 (key_handle 0x41b7022) of Java type 'crc64b0d4ce38c317adf3/NotificationService' as managed type 'ZipExtractMaui.Droid.NotificationService'.'

Answer (score 0):

`Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging` can work in the MAUI, but you need to use the old version. Please refer to this GitHub issue [Push Notification for MAUI #5458](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5458), and you could find the libraries needed in MAUI:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging" Version="122.0.0" />'
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Google.Dagger" Version="2.39.1" />'
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base" Version="117.6.0" />'
</ItemGroup>
```